# button in ion-option-button but i want it be vertical align

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

i wrote two button in a ion-option-button like this:

```
            <ion-option-button>
                <button class="button button-icon ion-ios-telephone-outline"></button>
                <button class="button button-icon ion-ios-trash-outline"></button>
            </ion-option-button>
```

and it shows like this:
[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEYPB.png)

but i want two button can align vertical like this:
[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAs7i.png)

can anyone tell me how to style it...?
thanks a lot...

the style i add flowing like this in scss:

```
            ion-option-button.button {
                background-color: #000;

                &.activated {
                    background-color: #000;
                }
                .button {
                    &:after {
                        content: '';
                        top: initial;
                        left: initial;
                        right: initial;
                        bottom: initial;
                    }
                    &.button-icon {
                        color: $light;
                        font-size: 26px;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: put your css code

Comment: you can ignore reset-this, and the others is original from ionic framework, not modified

Comment: i do not understand scss i can only give you a clear-css solution

Comment: @felixsturm you actually know `scss` if you know `css`. Take an hour to read the basics and you will gain that hour back quite fast on your next project, as you will have to write a lot less code to get the same result. The most useful and time saving features of `scss` are also the most simple to understand. You don't afford not to write `scss` instead of `css` if you want to keep up with the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ion-option-button {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around; /* optional */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

solution in pure css

```css
#vertical-menu {
  height: 180px;
  width: 56px;
}

.button {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  border: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}

.ion-ios-telephone-outline {
  background-image: url(http://mealthy.com.hk/images/icons/icon-phone.png);
}

.ion-ios-trash-outline {
  background-image: url(http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/white/trash-2-xxl.png);
}
```

```html
<div id="vertical-menu">
  <button class="button button-icon reset-this ion-ios-telephone-outline"></button>
  <button class="button button-icon reset-this ion-ios-trash-outline"></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could this be a css solution?

```
ion-option-button{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column; 
  width:10px;/**You have to manipulate this value*/
}
ion-option-button.button {
                background-color: #000;

                &.activated {
                    background-color: #000;
                }
                .button {
                    &:after {
                        content: '';
                        top: initial;
                        left: initial;
                        right: initial;
                        bottom: initial;
                    }
                    &.button-icon {
                        color: $light;
                        font-size: 26px;
                    }
```